# Karma / PhantomJS browser is started but no test result is displayed in the console

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, karma-runner

As described in the title, Karma starts PhantomJS browser but NO test result is displayed.
[image]

That's all what i get when i run `karma start karma.config.js` 
Works fine when i use Chrome or any other browser.

**EDIT:** 
my `karma.config.js` file :

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: '',

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    files: [
        '../../../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js',
        '../../../node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        '../app/**/*.js',
        'unitTest/*.js'
    ],

    exclude: [
    ],

    preprocessors: {
    },

    reporters: ['progress'],

    port: 9876,

    colors: true,

    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    autoWatch: false,

    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

    singleRun: false,

    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
Problem solved. All i needed was to turn on karma watcher (`autoWatch: true`).

Comment: plz add the `karma.config` file

Comment: I just did. Thank you!

Comment: thanks! same problem [and solution] here

Answer (score 0):

*To help others: the answer is in the question:*

> All i needed was to **turn on karma watcher** (`autoWatch: true`).